# reading jar file error

Tags: linux, tomcat, jar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNyGJ.png)

I was trying to run tomcat and I think these red files are causing problems.

does anyone know why I cant read .jar files?

Answer (score 1):

Do a `sudo ls -la` in the same directory to check for permissions of these files. 
Maybe you don't have proper read permissions for those files in red. To give read access use command like this `sudo chmod ug+r bootstrap.jar`. To give write access too `sudo chmod ug+rw bootstrap.jar`